# Regarding Windows-universal-samples of Microsoft

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, win-universal-app

Could any one tell me this code [1](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/ad9a0c4def222aaf044e51f8ee0939911cb58471/Samples/CameraOpenCV/cs/Scenario1_ExampleOperations.xaml.cs#L177) , is this function runs every time when it gets a new video frame, if yes then I made a thread after line 188 which basically make a TCP connection with the server and send that frame to server. But the problem is if this function runs every time it make every time new thread and make new socket connection, but I want this thread to make one time connection and then send frame every time it get to the already connected TCP socket. The thread I am making is with this code,

```
Task task = new Task(() => { _helper.TcpConnectAndSend(originalBitmap); });
task.Start();
```

[Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/ad9a0c4def222aaf044e51f8ee0939911cb58471/Samples/CameraOpenCV/cs/Scenario1_ExampleOperations.xaml.cs#L177)

Comment: Then don't use TcpConnectAndSend. Connect once and then call just Send for each frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want this thread to make one time connection and then send frame every time it get to the already connected TCP socket.

As Raymond Chen said, you called `TcpConnectAndSend` each time after [getting frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframereader.framearrived?view=winrt-22621) that will make connecting repeatedly.

The better way is connect TCP socket after camera **initialize**, and then call send method for each fream.

Comment: Okay, but first confirm me that I am right that in the above mentioned link, the function will call again whenever it will get the new frame?

Comment: Yep, it will be called when next frame arraived.

Comment: I done this way but in this way I figure out the frame is received with very high delay then previous method

Comment: But you give me the right direction so I am accepting it as a answer.